# Ajax-Call to get JSON Result from Controller (returning IList) in Asp.Net MVC always errors

Tags: c#, json, list, model-view-controller, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to make an AJAX-Call (Javascript) in order to get a `IList` created in a Controller-method.

index.js:

```
function getList() {
    $.ajax({
        url: myUrl, 
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",    
        success: function (response) {
            if (response) {
                //do sth
            }
        },
        error: function (response) {   
            alert("error");  //always error
            console.log(response); //object with just default functions
        }
   });

}
```

MyController.cs:

```
 public IList<SomeItem> loadList()
 {
        var items = db.SomeItemSet.Include(item => item.Sth).ToList();

        IList<SomeItem> resultList = new List<SomeItem>();

        for (int i = 0; i < items.Count(); i++)
        {
            //if(condition)
               resultList.Add(items[i]);                  
        }
        return resultList;
}

public JsonResult loadListJson()
{
    return Json(new { response = loadList() }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

A breakpoint in the Controllermethod shows me that it is executed. The list is not null.

I also tried to declare the method as Action Result (return json without jsonreqbehaviour) and doing type: POST in the ajax-Call. What do you think could fail here?

The network debugging panel shows the code

> 302:found

(but not 200:OK) when trying to loadListJson.

Exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: A circular reference was detected
>   while serializing an object of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.SomeItem_9D..'.    at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValueInternal(Object
>   o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse,
>   SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember)
>   at
>   ...

Comment: What's the actual error?  `alert("error")` doesn't tell you anything useful.  Examine the `response` variable.  Check your browser's developer console.  Examine the actual response from the server in your browser's network debugging panel.  It's probably telling you exactly what's wrong.

Comment: Log the response object to the console and see what's inside it.

Comment: It's unlikely to be the actual issue, but wrapping the list inside a sub-property (i.e. `new { response = loadList() }`) seems a bit pointless, unless you plan to add more properties in future? Just `return Json(loadlist(),...` would be sufficient and you'd get an array back. Anyway, as others have said, you don't need to guess (and you don't need us to guess) what is going wrong with your AJAX call...your browser provides Developer Tools for a reason. Check the Console and/or Network screens in your tools and see what is happening to your request.

Comment: I planned to add more props @ADyson .
Updated question

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks for the update. I think this is because you're trying to directly serialise an entity framework object, and by usually these contain circular references (e.g. a property which contains an object representing another related table, which itself has a property containing an object representing the first table, which contains...etc). And of course you can't represent a circular self-referencing data structure in a hierarchical textual data format such as JSON.

Comment: Use a view model.

Comment: The usual solution to this is to use a DTO / ViewModel object as an intermediary instead of serialising the EF object directly. It's good practice in any case, even if you don't have this issue. You can use a tool such as AutoMapper to ease the tedium of translating from the EF object to the DTO (and back again, if necessary). There is also a quick and dirty option to change your JSON serialisation settings to ignore circular references and truncate the object

Comment: P.S. You can easily google examples of both these approaches.

Comment: thanks a lot! solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert to convert my list !

index.js:

```
function getList() {
    $.ajax({
        url: myUrl, 
        type: "POST", //
        dataType: "json",    
    success: function (list) {
        if (list) {
            //do sth 
        }
    },
    error: function (response) { //do sth }
   });
}
```

MyController.cs:

```
 public ActionResult loadListJson()
        {
            return Content(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(loadList()), "application/json");
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there are circular references in your object structure .It is not supported by the JSON serializer. Try `Select()` method. Something like below.

```
 var items = db.SomeItemSet.Include(item => item.Sth).Select(s=> new SomeItemDto{
 // which properties you need
}).ToList();
```